# Help with the beginning of the game

Tags: lords-of-the-fallen

I got Lords of the Fallen for free with my Xbox Live Gold and I downloaded it and I'm playing it. However, I cannot get past the first part because I am terrible at fighting the first knight enemies.

Any strategies? I'm a brawler with the cleric equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The larger Rhogar are certainly formidable enemies. And indeed, even the other enemies are quite tough to kill, especially early on.

Follow these tips:

- Don't forget to lock on to enemies; this can be done by pressing the R3 button. This will focus the camera on the current enemy, allowing you to circle around them. Killing them, or pressing R3 again, will disengage the camera focus from that enemy.
- Make use of your potions; if you're losing, sprint away with L3, and use a potion.
- Block! A lot! Try to time your blocks when you see an attack incoming, and retaliate with a quick attack from there. Whittling away at health always works.
- Roll, or move around them! Some of the enemies early on are very slow, likely to help you learn the mechanics without punishing you too hard.

For the Cleric specifically:

- Prayer is a great spell. It creates a clone of you that distracts enemies from hitting you. Just be careful, not every enemy is dumb enough to fall for it entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Kaizerwolf, but I had asked this long ago and I am much farther in the game now.

Comment: Of course! I just downloaded the game for free from PSN for September, and I figured I would document my own struggles with the beginning of the game. :)